# Why am I not getting any data after Parsing this HTML data using TFHpple

Tags: html, swift, parsing, xpath, tfhpple

I am struggling to get any information back from my xPathQuery. The link I got using Chrome's developer tools, and did it by right clicking on the highlighted row in the screenshot attached. I'm creating a recipe-based app and am just playing around with single URL's before I try to scale it up. Help would be hugely appreciated!

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url=NSURL(string:"http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/roast_shoulder_of_lamb_92545")

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            var parser = TFHpple(HTMLData: data)

            var xPString = "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[186]/td[2]/span[3]"

            var nodes = parser.searchWithXPathQuery(xPString) as? [TFHppleElement]

            println(nodes)

        }

    })

    task.resume()


}
```

Comment: Well maybe because you declare a parser called "parser" and want to access it as "tutorialParser".searchWithXPathQuery from your tutorial.... maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rename the following line from

```
var nodes = tutorialParser.searchWithXPathQuery(xPString) as? [TFHppleElement]
```

to

```
var nodes = parser.searchWithXPathQuery(xPString) as? [TFHppleElement]
```

**Edit 1**

I just took a look at the html code from the url you try to parse... I made a search with safaris developer tools for the substring "tbody"... it seems there is no "tbody" defined in the html, so your parser won't be able to find it and maybe will give you a empty array like he is doing it currently...

could you try to search without the "tbody" in your xPString?

So go from

```
var xPString = "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[186]/td[2]/span[3]"
```

to

```
var xPString = "/html/body/table/tr[186]/td[2]/span[3]"
```

also is there a 186th tr tag in the table? a 2nd td in this tr and 3 spans in this td?

**Edit 2**

Ok, here is your parser....

https://gist.github.com/DennisWeidmann/27ea76b5aed4718cf4ce

and here is a usage example

https://gist.github.com/DennisWeidmann/a66ce53ad8691744d6a6

Comment: Oh I think I did that when posting it on here. no error message, simply "Nodes was nil.
[]"

Comment: ok lets test it step by step... I will go to github and take a look at the readme...

Comment: if it is possible that you explain me what you want to do, I maybe could give you a easier solution with NSScanner, or NSRegularExpression...?

Comment: there are also only 136 "tr"s in this document, including string "tr"s so your query string could definitely not be right.... take a look at it, I guess it will be the problem

Comment: I actually got that string just by right clicking on the html row in chrome developer tools and it gave me that. I'm essentially trying to scan through the html file, and dig out all the ingredients and put them into an array. here is the source code: view-source:http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/roast_shoulder_of_lamb_92545. any help would be hugely appreciated mate!

Comment: Ok, that is a bit of work I will have to code myself in xcode... I will shortly wire you up some lines and give you a simple method, which will return you an array of the ingredients...

Comment: Above you will find a gist of a parser example and the usage of it.... it will parse the url you give it and return you a dictionary holding two string arrays with your stuff in it.... cheers :-)

Comment: you're a genius dude, thank you. Can I ask one more question, it all makes sense to me but I'm just trying to wrap my head around the NSScanner method 'scan up to string'. So I get that youve created a pointer which you are updating after each scanUpToString method is called, but I can't grasp the method itself. Are you essentially scanning the code until the first 'stopString' is found, and then updating the pointer string to all the information that is found before the stopString? Or after? Thanks again

Comment: Hi, thanks... well its just some parsing :-) To your Question, the NSScanner works like this... At first you instantiate a NSScanner with a specific String to scan... After that you can use a couple of methods to scan the String... I used scanUpToString, because it scans to your substring and fills the pointer with with the string until there... So the interesting parts are "scanLocation", a property of the NSScanner instance holding the current position of the cursor, and the pointer which will be filled with the String...

Comment: Yes that makes sense. thanks for explaining it to me!